# SSAS mdx to find monthly retention rate of employees

Tags: ssas, mdx

Here is my scenario. I have a cube designed to track the hiring process of an applicant for a job. So, they go from applying, to hired, and sometimes to termination.

I want to find the number of employees that are hired in a particular month and see how many of these same employees are still around in each month after.

So 10 employees were hired in July 2012, I want to get the number that have not been terminated in August 2012 and so forth.

July 2012 Hired August 2012 Sept 2012
10 9 remain 7 remain

My measures are [Hired Qty] and [Termination Qty].
I have role playing dimensions for date: [Hire Date] and [Termination Date].

I was thinking I need to get the Hired Month as a set and then subtract out the Termination Qty for each month after by the Termination Date dimension.

Answer (score 2):

I think your design may not be optimal for solving this problem. In the past for student retention, I have used a **transition matrix** "pattern" as outlined here: [The Many-to-Many Revolution 2.0](http://www.sqlbi.com/articles/many2many/)

Let me know if you need more detail after looking through the solution.

To solve with your current model may require overly complex and non performant MDX calculations

Answer (score 0):

You can create a measure with this expression:

```
Sum(NonEmpty('employees set', ([Measures].[Hired Qty], 'a hire date')),
    ([Measures].[Termination Qty], 'a termination date'))
```

The first argument of Sum will return the employees that were hired at your chosen date.